# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException - Java

Tags: java, android, json

I'm relatively new to Android and I'm trying to parse some data and I seem to be getting the following error in LogCat:

```
Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException
```

I'm getting my JSON data from:
http://api.wunderground.com/api/180dde448747af27/forecast/q/UK/Bradford.json

I'm using the following code to pull out data:

```
JSONArray forecasts = json.getJSONArray("forecast");

for (int i=0;i<forecasts.length();i++) {                        
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    JSONObject e = forecasts.getJSONObject(i);

    // simpleforecast is a json array
    JSONArray forecastday = json.getJSONArray("forecastday");
    JSONObject fd = forecastday.getJSONObject(i);

    String icon = fd.getString("icon");

    map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
    map.put("icon", icon);
    mylist.add(map);            
}
```

I believe the error is something to do with my JSON pulling, I've probably not parsed it correctly, but I can't seem to find the correct way to get it out. This code is surrounded by a try-catch and then I've got a list adapter that I add the code to.

Apologies if I've missed anything but I'm fairly confident this is sufficient as I believe this is where the error is coming from.

Comment: If you don't catch the exception a line number should show up in LogCat and then you know which statement is causing it, should narrow your search a fair bit.

Comment: `forecast` isn't an array, use `getJSONObject` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse current json string as to get `icon` from `forecastday` JSONArray :

```
// get Json forecast object
JSONObject forecasts_obj = json.getJSONObject("forecast");
// get Json simpleforecast object
JSONObject simpleforecast_obj = forecasts_obj.getJSONObject("simpleforecast");

// get Json forecastday Array
JSONArray forecastday_arr = simpleforecast_obj.getJSONArray("forecastday");

for (int i=0;i<forecastday_arr.length();i++) {                        
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    JSONObject e = forecastday_arr.getJSONObject(i);

    String icon = e.getString("icon");
    map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
    map.put("icon", icon);
    mylist.add(map);            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it explains a lot and I've now got it working. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You misidentify forcast as a JSONArray.

[image: JSON]

So you should not using `JSONArray forecasts = json.getJSONArray("forecast");` to parse forecast, you should use `JSONObject forecastObj = json.getJSONObject("forecast")`. However, forecastday is a json array, so you can use `forecastObj.getJSONArray("forecastday")`, and then work on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very informative. I've now got it working.